# Numpy array iteration

Tags: python, numpy

Let´s say I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
an_array=np.array(['1601-3003-2105','3200-0000-0001','3200-0000-0002','93043','K036095','K036096'])
```

```
another_array=np.array(['3200-0000-0001','701450491A4CU',16])
```

I want to iterate over these arrays like this:

```
for elem in an_array:
    if elem in another_array:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

and then I am getting this output

[image]

How could I get the matching element as the resulting output, in this case 3200-0000-0001 element?

Comment: `print(elem)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.intersect1d` would do.

```
np.intersect1d(an_array, another_array)
```

returns :

```
array(['3200-0000-0001'], dtype='<U14')
```

Comment: Thanks to cyril, your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax sugar will help

```
ans=[i for i in an_array if i in another_array]
```

Comment: This works just as well, even better, if you use lists (instead of creating arrays).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean from the `another_array` as if you mean from `an_array` you can access the object directly as it is the `elem` object.

In this case you can do

```
itemindex = np.where(another_array==elem)
item = another_array[itemindex]
```

the first line returns the index in the array of the object and then the second line gets the object